# java zip contents of a folder instead of folder & winzip compatibility

Tags: java, zip

**UPDATE**

For issue #2 regarding the folder, I just replaced `ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(source + File.separator + file);` with `ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(file);`.

Issue remains with *WINZIP* not able to open the zipped file while *unzip* can unzip the file. WINZIP's error is: `Error: unable to seek to beginning of central directory.`

**ORIGINAL POST**

I have the following code that I have gotten and slightly modified from one of the questions on SO. In my application, I set OUTPUT_ZIP_FILE to `/var/tmp/test/test.zip` and my source folder as `/var/tmp/test`.

I have two problems:

1- Winzip does not recognize the zip file while unix unzip does - Not sure if this is due to #2 below

2- when I use unzip to unzip the file, it unzips the whole directory hierarchy: It creates `/var/tmp/test` inside of `/var/tmp/test` leading to `/var/tmp/test/var/tmp/test` and then the files inside that... I only want to zip the files and not the hierarchy...

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

    public class ZipFiles {

List<String> fileList;
String OUTPUT_ZIP_FILE;
String SOURCE_FOLDER;

ZipFiles() {
    fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public void zipIt(String ZipFiles) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    String source = "";
    Boolean shouldZip = true;
    try {
        try {
            // System.out.println("ZipFiles::zipIt::SOURCE_FOLDER::" +
            // SOURCE_FOLDER);

            source = SOURCE_FOLDER.substring(
                    SOURCE_FOLDER.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1,
                    SOURCE_FOLDER.length());
            // System.out.println("ZipFiles::zipIt::source::" + source);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            source = SOURCE_FOLDER;
        }
        for (String file : this.fileList) {
            if (file.endsWith("zip")) // This has already been zipped
            {
                shouldZip = false;
            }
        }
        if (shouldZip) {

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ZipFiles);
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

            // System.out.println("Output to Zip : " + ZipFiles);

            for (String file : this.fileList) {

                // System.out.println("File Added : " + file);
                ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(source + File.separator + file);
                zos.putNextEntry(ze);

                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(SOURCE_FOLDER
                        + File.separator + file);

                int len;
                while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }

                in.close();
            }

            zos.closeEntry();
            // remember close it
            zos.close();
        }
        // System.out.println("Folder successfully compressed");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void generateFileList(File node) {

    // add file only
    if (node.isFile()) {
        fileList.add(generateZipEntry(node.toString()));

    }

    if (node.isDirectory()) {
        String[] subNote = node.list();
        for (String filename : subNote) {
            generateFileList(new File(node, filename));
        }
    }

}

private String generateZipEntry(String file) {
    // System.out.println("ZipFiles::generateZipEntry::file::" + file);
    return file.substring(SOURCE_FOLDER.length(), file.length());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the update to my question, for issue #2: just replaced `ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(source + File.separator + file);` with `ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(file);`

For issue #1 with winzip, the zip file I was testing was actually being downloaded via my webapp. Problem was in my groovy side of the code actually:

```
  def download = {

   def folder = params.folder
   def file = new File( folder.toString())
   response.setHeader "Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=${file.name}"
   response.outputStream << file.text
   response.outputStream.flush()
   response.outputStream.close()
   }
```

When I replaced `outputStream <<file.text` with `outputStream << file.newInputStream()` everything worked correctly.
As for Unix' unzip, I was testing directly on the created file instead of the downloaded file!!!